# Struts 2 tabbedpanel is not displayed at all

Tags: jquery, struts2, dojo, struts2-jquery

am a newbie in struts 2 and i try desperately to insert tabbedpanel in a jsp
but nothink is displayed i tried using truts-dojo-tags and  struts-jquery-tags
My jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE taglib
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
<html>
<sx:head debug="true" parseContent="true" />
<body>
    <sx:tabbedpanel id="test">
        <sx:div id="one" label="one" labelposition="top">
       This is the first pane<br />
            <s:form>
                <s:textfield name="tt" label="Test Text" />
                <br />
                <s:textfield name="tt2" label="Test Text2" />
            </s:form>
        </sx:div>
        <sx:div id="two" label="two" labelposition="top">
        This is the first pane<br />
        </sx:div>
    </sx:tabbedpanel>
    <sj:tabbedpanel id="tabs">
        <sj:tab id="tab1" target="div1" label="tab no 1" />
        <sj:tab id="tab2" target="div2" label="tab no 2" />
        <sj:tab id="tab3" target="div3" label="tab no 3" />
        <div id="div1">...</div>
        <div id="div2">...</div>
        <div id="div3">...</div>
    </sj:tabbedpanel>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For the <sj:tabbedpanel ...> tag you also need the <sj:head /> tag inside of your head section. Please note that the dojo plugin is deprecated and will be removed in a future struts version.

Comment: thanks, but witch pluging will replace dojo?